# Eigenvalues of representations

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\rho$ be a representation of $G$ on $V$.  Why are its eigenvalues roots of unity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume $G$ is finite.  In that case any $g \in G$ has some finite order $n$, hence $\rho(g)^n = 1$.  It follows that the characteristic polynomial of $\rho(g)$ divides $x^n - 1$.